# How to search directory in a huge svn repository in a depth-limit manner?

Tags: svn

How can I do a dpeth-limited search efficiently on a SVN repository?

My company has a huge SVN repository which contains more than 100,000 folders and files. There are over 15 subsystems stored in the repository, and each subsystems has many branches. Now I am asked to write a script to search those branches which have match version code.

I know I can use command `svn list -R | grep 'version_code'`, but it is too slow. 
For local file system I can use command `find -type d -name 'version_code' -maxdepth 2` to perform a depth-limited search, however, svn does not provide a "find" subcommand.

What I want to do looks like:

```
svn find -type d -name 'version_code' -maxdepth 3
```

How can I achieve the same effect?